# How would I use these two Python chat room codes (server and client) to talk between different computers?

Tags: python, chat, server, tcp

I've been looking for a project to do over the winter holidays and have found some people's codes for Python Chat rooms.

I have both a server script, and a client script up and working. But i can only make it work if they are on the same computer. I've tried having the client on a different computer, but i can't seem to make it work (it says it can't connect).

Here is the server code:

```
# Tcp Chat server
import socket, select

#Function to broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast_data (sock, message):
    #Do not send the message to master socket and the client who has send us the message
    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection may be, chat client pressed ctrl+c for example
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # List to keep track of socket descriptors
    CONNECTION_LIST = []
    RECV_BUFFER = 4096 #exponent of 2
    PORT = 2015

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # this has no effect, why ?
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    # Add server socket to the list of readable connections
    CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_socket)

    print ("Chat server started on port " + str(PORT))

    while 1:
        # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(CONNECTION_LIST,[],[])

        for sock in read_sockets:
            #New connection
            if sock == server_socket:
                # Handle the case in which there is a new connection recieved through server_socket
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                CONNECTION_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print("Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr)

                broadcast_data(sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered room\n" % addr)

            #Some incoming message from a client
            else:
                # Data recieved from client, process it
                try:
                    #In Windows, sometimes when a TCP program closes abruptly,
                    # a "Connection reset by peer" exception will be thrown
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:
                        #broadcast_data(sock, "\r" + '<' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '> ' + data)
                        broadcast_data(sock, "\r" + data)

                except:
                    broadcast_data(sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                    print ("Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                    sock.close()
                    CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()
```

Here is the code for the client:

```
#Chat Client

import socket, select, string, sys
NName = ""
def prompt() :
    sys.stdout.write('<{0}> '.format(NName))
    sys.stdout.flush()

#main function
if __name__ == "__main__":

    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
        print('Usage : python TCP_Client.py hostname port')
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print('Unable to connect')
        sys.exit()

    print('Connected to remote host.')
    print('Enter your Nickname:')
    NName = raw_input(" ")
    prompt()

    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in read_sockets:
            #incoming message from remote server
            if sock == s:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print ('\nDisconnected from chat server')
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    prompt()

            #user entered a message
            else :
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()

                s.send("<{0}>  {1}".format(NName,msg))
                prompt()
```

I'm not looking for any improvements over the program, i just want to know how i'm supposed to make the client connect to the server from a different computer. 
Thanks,

Gibbon :)

***EDIT***

Okay, i realised i probably didn't have enough information here:

What I am doing at the moment:

In OSX terminal:

```
python /path/to/file/TCP_Server
```

And in another OSC terminal (On a different computer) (Replacing 'xxx.xxx...' with the computer running the server's ip addres:

```
python /path/to/file/TCP_Client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2015
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What were the arguments you used?

Comment: I ran the client with (in an OSX terminal): python /path/to/file/file.py 0.0.0.0 2015 
@tmr232

Comment: If both are running on the same computer you should use `client.py 127.0.0.1 2015`. `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP, it just tells to accept on all IPs related to the computer.

Comment: The problem is not that i can't run it when they are both on the same computer; but if they are not. I can't connect the client on one computer to the server if it's on another. @tmr232

Comment: You need to tell the client script the IP address of the machine that's running the server script. I don't use OSX, but I assume that you can find that in a few places. In the Terminal you'd use `ifconfig -a`; you may need to run that command as root. Also, you may need to modify your firewall settings.

Comment: How do you start the client?

Comment: I have added more information to the OP, firewall is okay.
But doing the above tells me the client can't connect...
@tmr232

Comment: @User I have added additional information to the original post, i think i'm running it right, but i dont know if i need to edit the code slightly??

Comment: @PM2Ring Uh, even if i tell the client script the IP address, it still isn't working.. Im not sure what's wrong.. Firewall is all fine, is there something i need to change in the script?? or are they both fine? Thanks,

Comment: I assume that the server computer and the client computer are both on the same LAN. :) Can you `ping` the server computer from the client computer ? And vice versa?

Comment: They are both on the same LAN, i tried to ping them, but it couldn't?? It shows a lot of time out messages.. @PM2Ring

Comment: Ok. Then either you need to fix your firewall configs so that the machines can ping each other. Or it may be that there's a config in your router that's blocking the traffic. But my bet's on the firewall on one or both machines. So as a first step, temporarily turn off the firewalls on both machines & see if you can ping.

Answer (score 0):

These Server/client codes are benefit and useful to learn and windows 10 u must modify smart screen, windows defender turn off.
I prefer that u can entered the 10.0.0.134/135/138 ip address with use wireless usb card and use wingIDE instead of IDLE environment of programming. Python is better than perl and is more flexibility than anothers programming like that php 7.0 I am fans of that. Go on python on azure microsoft and use for e-commerce destination.
Programming makes perfect with low level of language programming.